# css is not loading when proxy is enabled

Tags: html, css, proxy

I have a strange problem in my webpage , without proxy the webpage works fine . But when I enable proxy , the **CSS file** is not loading , it is **kept in the project resource folder**.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css"/>`

Can anybody help me over here?

Comment: Try using absolute path like `www.abc.com/.../xyz.css` or check the proxy settings which might be leaving css file as some smart code trace location of user on the basis of css file too!

Comment: I was linking a css file with absolute path before, but the proxy was blocking that link then I just downloaded and added to resource. Here the style.css is my own customization.Other js files and everything else picking from resource , Im not getting the actual reason why proxy is blocking the css link . :(

Comment: Proxy are designed to protect user, and that blocking if not taking place will reveal identity of user!!

Comment: may I ask which proxy you are trying!?

Comment: it is our  office proxy, if I use all those css styles inside my  html , there is no problem but , I dont prefer it. Is there any chance of blocking the "link " in proxy ? when linking to the CSS ..?

Comment: If its office proxy, then yes, there are chances of blocking that file, use socket proxy if you have one available in the same, that might allow everything i guess :)

Comment: well I will try , thanks :)